# How to read Excel File data in php while sending it via jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

This is my jquery code which sends data to php file -

```
jQuery("#btn_upload").click(function(){
    var exceldata = jQuery("#form_imput_field").serialize();
    var url = "phpfilepath/get-data-from-excel/exceldata/" + exceldata;
    if( exceldata != "" )
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        alert("I am in else");
    }
});
```

My PHP Method -

```
public function get-data-from-excel()
{
    //Get All Parameter data
    $params = $this->_getAllParams();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($params);die;
}
```

How can I read Excel data from this ? To create Excel I used `PHP EXCEL` previously but could get it to use in read as I dont know how to split data from this stream.

Current alert output - `MAX_FILE_SIZE=134217728`

Comment: ARe you actually sending an Excel file through jquery, or simply form data?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using file type input button from which I am passing an excel sheet

Comment: So you're uploading a file.... and from your last line in your question you're exceeding the max filesize...not so much an Excel question as a file upload question.... look to your php.ini settings for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Comment: @MarkBaker I will change the settings but still I want to know how I handle it..or how do I split data..although size is 12.0 KB (12,288 bytes)

Comment: You can't even read the file in PHP unless you can upload it.... if the filesize is 12,288 bytes and PHP says MAX_FILE_SIZE=134217728 then there's a disagreement. Once you've uploaded the file (assuming you're using PHPExcel) look at the documentation and some of the basic examples provided.... there's tons of information there about reading Excel files

Comment: @MarkBaker can you please provide me the link for the documentation where I can search for ?

Comment: Link to the documentation: it's in the folder called /Documentation in the standard PHPExcel distribution... if you downloaded a distribution without documentation, then go back to the codeplex site and download the docs via the download tab

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit a `<input type="file"/>` tag using JQuery and AJAX bad news, you can't do that with JQuery alone. You need to use a plugin to archieve that. For example [iframe-post-form](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/iframe-post-form).

Once you have the excel file in your server (stored in some temporal dir for example) you should be able to read it using PHPExcel.php